# 'redirect_url' not returned in curl_getinfo

Tags: php, curl

I wrote code similar to following to get a redirect url, this code works fine on my local machine, however on my hosting server, the 'redirect_url' is not supported by the curl version on the host server, do you know how can I solve this? i.e., how can I achieve the same goal (issue a http request with referer and then get the redirect url without the help of 'redirect_url'), thanks!

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 

$referer= "xxx";
$url = "xxx";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

$redirect_url = $info['redirect_url'];

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Well, if that feature is not supported you cannot use it. What is your question in this?

Comment: I want to achieve the same goal, i.e., issue a http request with referer, then get the redirect url.

Comment: You should be able to analyse the headers contained in the result curl returns, when you use the option to include the headers in the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)**, `curl_getinfo` does not return an array key named `"redirect_url"`. Perhaps you need `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`, or the array key `"url"`:

- `$redirect_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);`

  *Or*
- `$redirect_url = $info["url"];`

**`CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`** is the last effective url, so if a request was redirected then the **final** url will be here.

---

Also, note that if you want curl to follow the redirect then you will need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` before making the request:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution I did is allowing the plugin to return headers and extract the location parameters

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$exec=curl_exec($ch);
$x=curl_error($ch);
$cuinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);

if( $cuinfo['http_code'] == 302 && ! isset($cuinfo['redirect_url']) ){

    if(stristr($exec, 'Location:')){


        preg_match( '{Location:(.*)}' , $exec, $loc_matches);
        $redirect_url = trim($loc_matches[1]);

        if(trim($redirect_url) !=  ''){
            $cuinfo['redirect_url'] = $redirect_url;
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP **5.3.7**   Introduced CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL.
See that you don't have an older version

Answer (score 0):

CURL doesn't have `redirect_url`, instead it uses `url`, so replace this:

```
$redirect_url = $info['redirect_url'];
```

with this:

```
$redirect_url = $info['url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I use curl without FOLLOWLOCATION, I get a redirect_url element in curl info. This simplify the task for "manual" redirection, but it seems it depends on curl version.

The alternative is to analyze response header and get redirect url from there. This can help:
http://slopjong.de/2012/03/31/curl-follow-locations-with-safe_mode-enabled-or-open_basedir-set/